# PHP read from uploaded text file?

Tags: php, file, upload

If I upload a text file via a form, is it possible to output its contents directly from the $_FILES variable rather than saving it onto the server first?  I know this is a security risk, but it will only be run on a local machine.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The file is saved to temp directory the moment it's uploaded, but you can use `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']` to read it without having to save in a permanent place.

Comment: Doh, I was doing this all along, but the HTML was nothing that would be visible on the page.  I'm using chrome, so when I clicked view source, it showed me a re-loaded version of the page, where the text file had not been loaded:)

Answer (score 81):

Doing

```
file_get_contents($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']);
```

is valid however you should also check to make sure that the file was uploaded through a form and that no errors occurred during upload:

```
if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK               //checks for errors
      && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'])) { //checks that file is uploaded
  echo file_get_contents($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']); 
}
```

A helpful link is https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Hi, why should I check file via is_uploaded_file? Is there some security issue? What problem it can cause? Can you explain it to me or provide some link to post? Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, no. At least not through the $_FILES variable. Sorry.

EDIT: It is always saved as the temp file in $_FILES and you'll always have to use that one for content.

Comment: Okay, fine, I'll just not post when I know the answer is bad news!

Comment: This answer is strictly true because the question asked specifically about the $_FILES variable but I think the other answers are correct for what the post seems to ask!

Comment: Yeah like Lukos said, you got it wrong, "Unfortunately, no" is incorrect. You can get the contents from an uploaded file without saving it