# Open a file type in php

Tags: php, file

I am trying to open a file in php.

this is my code:

```
IF (ISSET($_POST['submit']))
{
    $filename = $_POST['file'];
    echo $filename; 
    $file =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $myfile = fopen($file, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    echo fread($myfile,filesize($file));
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

and this is the form :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action ="action.php" method ="post">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Cruncher</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="uploadfile" class="col-lg-2 control-label">BOM Open File:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <input type = "file" class="form-control" name = "file">
            <br/>
            <button type ="submit" name ="submit" class ="btn btn-primary"> Convert File </button>
            </div>
            </div>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
```

I believe that this code can open any type of file (correct me if I am wrong),  but instead of reading the file I get this error message:

```
Unable to open file!
```

Can you please help me with this, please I need help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you not need to store  the file temporaryly on a server to read it?

Comment: can you pls post the var_dump of $_FILES

Comment: Please have a look at this question. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201379/php-read-from-uploaded-text-file

Comment: @donald123 it only shows NULL,

Comment: then you did't have an upload! pls check your form

Comment: please post the form, could be that the input have different name

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1534463/vikas-umrao is right, enctype="multipart/form-data" is mandatory for forms with files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form as

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action ="action.php" method ="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```